# Plain attribute or attribute with field?

Tags: c#, class, properties, field

I see a lot of code snippets with this example:

```
    private string _possessor;
    public string Possessor
    {
        get { return _possessor; }
        set { _possessor = value; }
    }
```

My questions is, why not just use plain property as in:

```
    public string Possessor { get; set; }
```

I was reading on the internet, but could not really see the difference? You can either way set values in both examples and second example requires less coding and looks cleaner.

Comment: If it is just that, it _may be_ somewhat old legacy code, where auto-properties weren't a thing, yet. The feature has been added in C# 3 (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)). But even after its introduction, there are always people that are reluctant to adopt new language features (or are simply unaware thereof).

Comment: It is a matter of style, until you need to put some logic in the getter and/or setter, then you need to fully implement the property, or use expression body members, which is another thing you might see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that you are showing, it's true, there are no differences on doing each approach and the second one is cleaner. Knowing the first approach is useful because sometimes you need a property to do more than just get/set so in that case you will need to use the first approach.

You can also see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) that with each new c# version, different ways of implement properties were created. The second approach is `Auto-implemented properties`

Comment: "Cleaner"? Well it's shorter and (in my opinion) more readable, but behind the scenes, it's the exact same thing. So, depends on your definition of "clean".

Comment: It seems the link is dead. @Fildor, I think if it's less code and does the same functionality, it is definitely cleaner at the end of the day? Easier to find whatever You need in class or similar things.

Comment: @Tobi fixed the link

Comment: @Tobi As I say: In a way, yes. But it depends on what you consider "clean".

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of doing this is to help achieve data Encapsulation, which helps us by   hidden the data in a class from other classes. this is also known as data-hiding.
Another good reason why this is done is when there some special validation or special business rules that needs to be checked before we set that particular value.

You can read more on Encapsulation from this site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-encapsulation/